# Python Flask Blueprint inject a variable value to all contexts globally?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, templating, blueprint

I have the following app.py:

```
def create_app(env_name) -> Flask:
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.register_blueprint(foo1, url_prefix="/foo1")
    app.register_blueprint(foo2, url_prefix="/foo2")
    app.register_blueprint(foo3, url_prefix="/foo3")
    return app
```

and the following main.py:

```
from .app import create_app
app = create_app(env_name)
app.run(HOST, PORT)
```

and inside the individual blueprints / controllers / contexts, I defined a function which is needed by the template of the application:

```
foo1app = Blueprint("foo1", __name__)
@foo1app.context_processor
def inject_now():
    return {'now': datetime.utcnow()}
```

Currently I copy-paste the code snippet above to ALL blueprints / controllers / contexts. Is there a way to inject the `now` globally without this code duplication? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
foo1app = Blueprint("foo1", __name__)
@foo1app.app_context_processor
def inject_now():
    return {'now': datetime.utcnow()}
```

From the `Blueprint` class:

- `context_processor`: Like `Flask.context_processor` but for a blueprint. This function is only executed for requests handled by a blueprint.
- `app_context_processor`: Like `Flask.context_processor` but for a blueprint. Such a function is executed each request, even if outside of the blueprint.

Comment: I don't understand how this would solve my problem.